# Table border style

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is how I style tables now:

```
#content table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #222; 
}
#content table td {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    padding: .3em;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have tables with black outside border (#222). However, I want the inside border to be lighter color (let's say #888). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a div container for the table and set it's border as required. Then simply set the table border independently?

Markup:

```
<div class='outerDiv'>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.outerDiv{ border:solid 2px #222; }
.outerDiv table { border:solid 2px #888; }
```

Comment: In this case this will work,  but if you're not setting the width of the table this solution will present challenges;  the container will be full width (it's a block-level element) and the table will determine its own width.  Floating the container could cure this,  but bring more challenges

Comment: @GlennG: I provided a solution based on the CSS provided to date. I wouldn't float a div element in your scenario when I can just set the div to display:inline-block to only stretch as much as needed. That way I don't have to worry about clearing any further elements later on in the DOM.